# C++ Right Shift, XOR problems

Tags: c++, xor

I have this sample code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "math.h"
#ifndef uint32
#define uint32 unsigned long int
#endif
#define L(a) printf("\n%x >> 1 = %x", a, a>>1)
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    uint32 a = 2941362065;
    uint32 b = 509727776;
    uint32 c = a ^ b;
    L(a^b);
    printf("\n%x >> 1 = %x", c , c>>1);
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that L(a) returns

```
b1304bb1 >> 1 = a0617581
```

while

```
printf("\n%x >> 1 = %x", c , c>>1);
```

returns

```
b1304bb1 >> 1 = 589825d8
```

The last value is the one that appears to be correct as the windows calculator returns it.
This code is running on WinXP 32. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, that's what you get for using macros, you deserve that. The point is that `L(a^b)` becomes `a^b>>1` which is then evaluated as `a^(b>>1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting bitten by the way macros in C work.  The right shift has a higher precedence than xor, so it will happen first.  You should surround every instance of `a` in the definition of L with parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

```
L(a^b) becomes printf("\n%x >> 1 = %x", a^b, a^b>>1)
```

Precedence of >> is 5 while ^ is 9 (see [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)), that means that the call above gives same results as the following (note additional parenthesis):

```
printf("\n%x >> 1 = %x", a^b, a^(b>>1))
```

You should change your L definition by adding parenthesis around the arguments:

```
#define L(a) printf("\n%x >> 1 = %x", (a), (a)>>1)
```

Better to use a function instead of L macro.

Comment: Many thanks. That solved my mistery. I could'n sleep for couple of nights beciuse of that.

Answer (score 1):

The macro is expanding to:

```
printf("\n%x >> 1 = %x", a ^ b, a ^ b >> 1)
```

Since `<<` has higher precedence than `^` (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)), it was being processed as `a ^ (b >> 1)`, not `(a ^ b) >> 1`.

You need parentheses in your macro:

```
#define L(a) printf("\n%x >> 1 = %x", (a), (a)>>1)
```

In general, you should usually put parentheses around macro parameters that can be expressions. Unlike function calls, macro parameters are not evaluated before the call, they're just substituted in as text. So you can easily get unexpected grouping like this.

But an even better guideline is to not use a macro when a function will work just as well.